# Eclipse: Autosave and Build does not work

Tags: eclipse, launch

I use Eclipse version 2021-03 on Windows 10.
In the preferences I checked the following options:

General -> Workspace -> Build -> Build automatically

Run/Debug -> Launching
[image]

When I change the content of a Java file and then launch a run configuration, where this Java file is contained in the dependencies, then the file is not saved and no build is performed before the launch.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Contained in what dependencies? It seems likely that Eclipse doesn't think it is a dependency

Comment: The file is included in a project, which is included in the ClassPath entries in the run configuration. So I think Eclipse should know, that the run configuration depends on that file.

Comment: No, it won't look at the Run Configuration. Add the project containing the file to the "Project References" in the first project's Properties.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Since my app loads other modules dynamically by looking at some annotations, the project which contains the main class does not know about these dynamically loaded projects. By addding these to the 'Project References' the problem is solved.